# Convert old style SQL statement to current SQL with explicit JOIN logic

Tags: mysql, join

We have and EDI application that uses a MySQL back end to store all of the relevant records. The EDI application use a drag and drop style wizard to create the SQL statement so it is very limited in what can be created. This is fine for the existing requirement, which is just to extract the customer purchase order header and line information. It just requires the simple join between header and line tables.

```
SELECT  
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."Buy-from Vendor No_" AS CustInternalShipToRef,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."No_" AS CustPONumber,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Line No_" AS POLineItemNumber,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Vendor Item No_" AS IntProductCode,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."No_" AS CustomerProductCode,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Quantity" AS Quantity,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Unit of Measure" AS OrderQuantityUOM ,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Expected Receipt Date" AS RequestedDeliveryDate,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Direct Unit Cost" AS PricePerUnit,
FROM  
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header",
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line",
WHERE 
    ("dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."No_"="dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Document No_") 
    AND ("dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."Buy-from Vendor No_" Like '%AJAX%') 
    AND ("dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."Order Date" >= getdate()-2) 
    AND ("dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."Status" = '1') 
    AND ("dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Quantity" > '0')
```

Now we have a need to include a 3rd table, which is also possible with the existing 'wizard', but we can't use an inner join as the 3rd table doesn't have a matching record for every one of the records in the 1st table. So now I need to convert the old style SQL to the current syntax and include more explicit join logic.

The outcome I am trying to achieve is to display ALL the existing fields from the SELECT section as per the criteria in the WHERE section and then display header comments from the purchase order comments table IF they exist.

I have been looking through posts on here to try to get at least a starting point. So I have put together the below statement and am looking to get some feedback on whether the logic I have used will achieve the outcome I am looking for above. Also not sure if I should be using just LEFT JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT  
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."Buy-from Vendor No_" AS CustInternalShipToRef,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."No_" AS CustPONumber,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Line No_" AS POLineItemNumber,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Vendor Item No_" AS IntProductCode,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."No_" AS CustomerProductCode,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Quantity" AS Quantity,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Unit of Measure" AS OrderQuantityUOM ,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Expected Receipt Date" AS RequestedDeliveryDate,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Direct Unit Cost" AS PricePerUnit,
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purch_ Comment Line"."Comment" AS OrderComments
FROM  
    "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"
    LEFT JOIN (
        "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header" INNER JOIN "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line" ON "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."No_"="dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Document No_"
        AND "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."Buy-from Vendor No_" Like '%AJAX%'
        AND "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."Order Date" >= getdate()-2
        AND "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."Status" = '1'
        AND "dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Line"."Quantity" > '0'
    ) ON "dbo"."Supplier live$Purch_ Comment Line"."No_"="dbo"."Supplier live$Purchase Header"."No_"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you overthought it a little. Try to just add your new table as a LEFT JOIN if the records already meet your criteria in the original query.

```
Select t1.Col1 , t2.Col2 , nt1.Col3 
From Dbo.OriginalTable1 t1 
JOIN dbo.OriginalTable2 t2 ON t2.col1 =t1.col1
And t2.col2 =t1.col2 
LEFT JOIN dbo.NewTable1 nt1 On nt1.col1 = t1.col1
```

The above will return all records that meet the join criteria in tables 1 and 2. The Col3 would be populated where a match in the join exists and null where is doesn't. The last left join does not limit the resulting data set.

Comment: I'm on the mobile app, so my app logins for not using your original code.

Comment: Thanks Vinnie. Simpler is usually better, I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Applied this on the customer side and it gives us exactly what we need. Thanks for your help.